# SVG images are not loading in android webview

Tags: android, svg, webview

[image]

I have a list of svg images i am receiving from android webview. Which all seem to be not load intead show up like this. Everything else like text and png images are loading without any issues. Is there a way to enable svg images for webview by default?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I converted them to png and used them.

Comment: You can share an example how you have achieved it

Comment: just use online tools to convert SVG to PNG and put that in the code. I was facing an issue in illustrations, I redownloaded them from the same website in PNG format. But there are a lot of online tools available to convert SVG to PNG